# Resizing tableHeader fails on iPhone5

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am resizing the tableheader, which is a view, in my table, called `detailedInterestTableView`.  This method is placed in the `(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. This works, when run from iPhone 6 or iPhone 6+. When it is run on my iPhone 5 this code does not affect the UI at all, and the tableheader remains unchanged.

Is this code only applicable to certain devices (iPhone 6 and beyond)? What would cause it to look different on my iPhone 5 compared to iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+? They are both running on version 9.2.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    CGRect newFrame = self.detailedInterestTableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height-92;
    self.detailedInterestTableView.tableHeaderView.frame = newFrame;
    [self.detailedInterestTableView setTableHeaderView:self.detailedInterestTableView.tableHeaderView];
}
```

iPhone 6/6+. The white space below photo (which holds like/dislike/comment buttons) is correct:

[image]

iPhone5. The white space below photo (which holds like/dislike/comment buttons) is incorrect. It is way too large.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the frame height using a relative change : `-92`
So if the frames are not the same originally, the result will be different too. Try using a fixed value.

Try replacing

```
newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height-92;
```

By

```
newFrame.size.height = 500; // Or any other value that fits
```